# What is an example of a modern build and CD pipeline for C++?

Tags: c++, unit-tests, continuous-integration, performance-testing

Software Engineering common practices change over time.
What is an example (Linux-based) stack of a modern build & release pipeline for C++ with continuous integration and delivery.

As of 2022, with release of **C++ 20** (with modules); what are some up-to-date open-source solutions, a combination that includes the following? (At least C++17)

- A package manager (e.g. `conan.io`)
- Test framework (e.g. [`googletest`](https://github.com/google/googletest))
- Build tool (e.g. `make`, `CMake`, etc; Are there newer tools?)
- A CI/CD pipeline for release (e.g. circleci, Jenkins, github Actions, etc) with a scripting language(s): `bash`, `groovy`.
- Compiler (Should be suitable for multiple target platforms using multiple compilers for each release: `gcc++`, `clang++`) and producing artifacts (documentations etc)
- Various test types (unit, integration, mocking, maybe profiling or performance testing)
- Linter
- Other items I might have missed

I know there are many variations and tastes. But what is a **mature** combination that you know of and have worked well together and in a medium-sized or large sized company with agile teams and workflows.

Ideally, a good C++ github repo with workflows set up that represent an industry-standard combination of above items, would be ideal.

Related but different questions: [1](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/395084/windows-have-a-dedicated-ms-visual-c-c-toolchain), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517662/what-is-platform-toolset-setting-in-visual-studio-project).

Comment: Might be related:  Most Popular C++ Unit Testing Frameworks (reddit): https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/4e9afx/most_popular_c_unit_testing_frameworks/

Comment: an example: https://github.com/andreasfertig/cppinsights

Comment: Jetbrains' State of ecosystem for C++: https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/devecosystem-2021/cpp/

Answer (score 1):

Some items I found:

- LLVM: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project
- Chromium: [toolchain on googlesource](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/build/+/refs/heads/main/toolchain)
- Google Test itself has its CI: https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/main/ci

Worth looking:

- https://lefticus.gitbooks.io/cpp-best-practices/content/02-Use_the_Tools_Available.html